# i want to get data from textbox in php

Tags: php

I hav created a group of textboxes using a loop and its names are unique and names are assigned using variable ( like ). Then How can i retrieve the values in that textboxes after a button click with in a loop. Really I cant move from here. Can anyone plz help me..
Part of the my code is given below

```
$q1="select * from result where s_id=$sid";
$res1=mysql_query($q1,$link) or die($q1);
echo '<form action="editresultprofile.php?sid=$sid">';
while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1))
    {
    echo '<td><input type="text" name='.$row1['sub_name'].' class="textfield" value='.$row1['result'].'></td>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="update" ></form>';
```

Comment: Nice HTML injection vulnerabilities... I hope none of those values you're inserting have a `"` in them...  beyond that, http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: just out of curiosity where did you learn to write like that? its not your fault but they are putting you on the wrong road. The php manual is a much better source for code snippets/hints/deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible through PHP. You have use javascript to get the values in the textbox at realtime.

But using php, you have submit the form first, and then only you will get the data on the page its submit the data too. For example as per your question, only `editresultprofile.php` will be able to get the data values.

On `editresultprofile.php`, you can do

```
$name = $_POST['thesubname']; //You have to change the name to what is reflected on your case
```

However, if you use javascript, you can get the values as they were typed, before submitting the form.

```
function getValues(){
  var tbox = document.getElementById('yourtextboxid');
  alert(tbox.value);
  return false; //stop the submisison
}
```

Attach the function in the `onSubmit` event of the form.

```
<form onsubmit="return getValues()" >
```